# Store sftp file names to local variable in Unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am trying to execute few commands on sftp from unix box part of my script in interactive mode. I need list of files available back in unix variable. I am trying to find a way but not able to do so yet. Can someone please help me here ?

Here is my code which is part of a script.

```
       ## some other code

       Count= $(except - c"
              spawn sftp $USER@$HOSTNAME
              sleep 2
              expect \"servername password:\"
              send  \"$PASSWORD\r\"
              sleep 2
              expect \"sftp>\"
              send \"ls FileName*\r\"
              sleep 2
              send \"bye\r\"
              interact"
              )
        ## some other code
```

approach 2:
  with approach 2 I have put cd and ls cmd in $cmd , however it works if I execute directly but it does nt work if I put it like below to get values.

```
count = "$(sftp -i key -b $cmd  $USER@$HOSTNAME)"
```

Thank you

Comment: That is not Bash syntax. You want `count="$(…)"`.

Comment: I tried and it thrown an error

Comment: You can use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check your syntax.

Comment: If you have `rsync` try `rsync host.name.com:directory/path/'*'`  else try `ssh user@host ls -l /some/directory`. `sftp`  is used for file transfer.

Comment: I tried ssh , it failed , "PTY allocation request failed on channel" , Shell request failed on channel. This is what I am getting ,